# Node.js Async file open and read operation gives out of bound errors

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

I have the following function to look for changes in a file, open the file and read the said changes. For this I use fs.statSync to calculate the length of my buffer.

```
var allFiles=[logfile]
allFiles.forEach (function (file) {
  var fName = file;
  var fNameStat = new Object;

  fNameStat = fs.statSync(fName);

  if (!fNameStat.isFile()) {
    console.log(fName + ' is not a file');
    process.exit(1);
  }

  console.log('watching ' + fName + ' bytes: ' + fNameStat.size);

  fs.watch(fName, function (event, filename) {
    var fNameStatChanged = fs.statSync(fName);
    console.log('file changed from ' + fNameStat.size + ' to ' + fNameStatChanged.size);
    fs.open(fName, 'r', function(err, fd) {
    var newDataLength = fNameStatChanged.size - fNameStat.size;
    var buffer = new Buffer(newDataLength, 'utf-8');
    fs.readSync(fd, buffer, 0, newDataLength, fNameStat.size, function (err, bytesRead, newData) {
     if (err) {
        console.log(err);
     };
     logline = newData.toString()
     console.log(logline);
    socket.emit("log-tail",logline);
  });
  fNameStat = fs.statSync(fName);
});

}); // fs.watch

}); // allFiles.forEach
```

But I get a buffer outofbounds error. This happens when the log file gets two messages one after the other.

```
file changed from 40756 to 40789
file changed from 40756 to 40844
fs.js:620
  binding.read(fd, buffer, offset, length, position, req);
          ^

Error: Offset is out of bounds
```

I am assuming its to do with the asynchronous calls. The file changes before the first read operation is complete and as such the buffer is wrong. But even after using the corresponding synchronous calls the code doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: did you try to throttle fs.watch events ?

Comment: @mh-cbon No. Not really sure how to either. Do you mean that I should only watch for some type of changes or is it a nodejs function. I am new to it all so apologies

Comment: Also i don't want to lose any change events. I am basically implementing a tail-f functionality so need to keep track of all the changes to a file

Comment: I suspect those two are consecutive `file changed from 40756 to 40789`
`file changed from 40756 to 40844`. If you d catch only the last one, that would not loose any data, as they start on the same offset. And BTW, if you d read those two consecutively with success, you d send data from 40756 to 40789 twice to the other end.

Comment: Yes. But the trouble is how do I go about catching this sort of event with both changes having the same start buffer. Is there a way to know any concurrent pending calls

Comment: Its kind of a hack but I solved this by explicitly checking if newDataLength is equal to 0 and if so to just return without doing the read. This may lead to a dropped message once in a while but for my purpose its more important to have the server not crash rather than drop a message. So while this works for me, it wont work for everyone

Comment: give it a check https://css-tricks.com/debouncing-throttling-explained-examples/ Try debounce, not throttle as i said... https://lodash.com/docs#debounce https://www.npmjs.com/package/lodash.debounce